# Xamarin Plugin.Toast System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make a toast message in Xamarin.Forms with the Plugin.Toast Nuget-Package.

Class for calling Toast:

```
using Plugin.Toast;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Essentials;

namespace toast.service
{
    public class toast
    {

        public void toastWarning(string msg)
        {
          CrossToastPopUp.Current.ShowToastWarning(msg, Plugin.Toast.Abstractions.ToastLength.Short);
        }

    
    }
}
```

Calling toast code:

```
service.toast toast = new service.toast();
toast.toastWarning("test");
```

But I alwas get this error:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: If you want help specific to your code, at least figure out *what* is `null`, first. If, after doing that, you can't figure out *why* it's `null`, then post a question.

Comment: that plugin has not been updated in 2 years

Comment: if you can provide more details like the error stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use a Plugin. `Xamarin` provide `Android.Widget.Toast` library to show message.

```
   Toast.MakeText(this, "Received intent!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
```

[image]